# Possible to ignore/exclude file/folder from .editorconfig?

Tags: editorconfig

Is it possible to ignore/exclude file/folder from .editorconfig?

Reason: I have a `/vendor` folder with third party files. I don't want the folder to inherit any of my `.editorconfig` configs.

I found the [EditorConfig-Properties](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties) page and seems like there's no property to exclude folders. Maybe there's a hack to make it possible?

**current config**

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
indent_style = tab
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I could just tighten up the rules. Instead of a catch-all `[*]` I could specify with folders to include instead of trying to exclude folders. Is there a way to do a only-in-root rule?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Another solution to ignore `/vendor` folder:

- match the path you want to ignore
- set `unset` to property you want to ignore

For example, if you have:

- /index.html
- /vendor
- /.editorconfig

You can match all files in the `vendor` directory in your `.editorconfig` and ignore all properties (set to IDE's default):

```ini
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Ignore paths
[/vendor/**]
charset = unset
end_of_line = unset
insert_final_newline = unset
trim_trailing_whitespace = unset
indent_style = unset
indent_size = unset
```

Comment: I think this is a much better solution as it keeps all the editorconfig in one place.

Comment: The "official" way is to set them to `unset`. The editorconfig plugin for VS Code also suggests it as part of its Intellisense. Any invalid value will work though.

Comment: for my .jinjalintconfig.py file, if i use unset, ignore, or ignore, I get NameError: name '' is not defined

Comment: This answer should be updated to use the now documented value of `unset`. Otherwise this answer is 100% on point.

Answer (score 17):

You can create an `.editorconfig` file in `vender/` with a simple `root = true` line.

Comment: Does not work for me. The .editorconfig get modified with the config of the parent folder one.

Comment: @avandecreme You should only have one line in the `.editorconfig` file. `root = true` is not in any sections.

Comment: Yes that is what I had but sections got automatically added somehow. Maybe a bug with the netbeans plugin.

Comment: @avandecreme Can you report it as a bug to the Netbeans plugin?

Comment: @xuhdev but the vendor or node_modules directories is not versioned, so the .editorconfig into these directories is not a option. Exists other way?

Comment: @Maykonn Can you create the directory, add `.editorconfig` and version this file?

Comment: @xuhdev I just tried doing that and the answer is yes, but not without problems. Every time I run `yarn` it deletes my `node_modules/.editorconfig` file, even though it's checked into Git.

Answer (score 13):

In IntelliJ there is a WONDERFUL feature that arrived just a month ago:

```
ij_formatter_enabled = true/false
```

Just match a pattern or a file type in your `.editorconfig` and matched resources are ignored:

```
[{**/*.sql,**/*.properties,**/File.kt}]
ij_formatter_enabled = false
```

Thank you JetBrains!

Comment: Can I also match whole folders with this?

Comment: I would think so, with `templates/*` for example... but it's easy to check and find out so give it a go :)

Answer (score 10):

Best way I've found is to add this to an otherwise blank `.editorconfig` in the folder you want to ignore:

```
[*]
generated_code = true
```

Comment: Note, this is not (yet) part of the core editorconfig standard, so YMMV as to whether this works in your environment (e.g. VSCode Editorconfig Extension does not support this, while Visual Studio does). https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/399

Answer (score 5):

Combining others' answers in this thread to create the following solution to simply turn off the .editorconfig wholesale for the files within a folder, while still keeping it in the base .editorconfig file. Note: this is new as of VS 2019 16.5, according to Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022).

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Ignore paths
[*/Migrations/*]
generated_code = true
```