# C# formatting with .editorconfig: can I use a different naming style for unit tests?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, editorconfig, dotnet-format

Is there a way to specify in an `.editorconfig` file that I want to use a different naming style for my Unit tests?

Currently we're using something like this: `GetAll_GivenNoCustomers_ReturnsEmptyList` but I get the suggestion to remove the underscores from the name: `GetAllGivenNoCustomersReturnsEmptyList` and the `dotnet format` command actually changes this.

For all our other methods this behavior is desired, just not for our tests.

Is there a way to treat our unit tests differently?
Like a way to sense the presence of the `[Test]` attributes before the method definition?
Or (less preferred) exclude our test projects from this naming rule?

I would like to keep all rules in one single `.editorconfig` file, which we would like to distribute across different applications and users in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

My undestanding is that you can place a different `.editorConfig` in the UnitTest project folder, and it will take those instead.

From http://docs.editorconfig.org/en/master/editorconfig-format.html:

> Filename and Location

> When a filename is given to EditorConfig a search is performed in the directory of the given file and all parent directories for an EditorConfig file (named ".editorconfig" by default). All found EditorConfig files are searched for sections with section names matching the given filename. The search will stop if an EditorConfig file is found with the root property set to true or when reaching the root filesystem directory.

> Files are read top to bottom and the most recent rules found take precedence. If multiple EditorConfig files have matching sections, the rules from the closer EditorConfig file are read last, so properties in closer files take precedence.

You need to watch for `root = true`

Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348831/486564 regarding adding rules for certain folders from the `.editorConfig` file.

Comment: We're actually in an effort to create one main `.editorConfig` file to counteract the sprawl of formatting rules over all our different applications and developer machines and settings. So if at all possible I would like to avoid introducing an extra file.

Comment: I modified the wording of my answer. Please see the answer linked below. You can have specific rules for specific folders. In the case of the answer, the rules are to ignore everything, but you can have your own formatting rules there.